# the dir function in python

Tags: python

```
help(dir):
```

> ```
> dir([object]) -> list of strings        
> If called without an argument, return the names in the current scope.  
> Else, return an alphabetized list of names comprising (some of) the attributes  
> of the given object, and of attributes reachable from it.  
> If the object supplies a method named __dir__, it will be used; otherwise  
> the default dir() logic is used and returns:  
>   for a module object: the module's attributes.  
>   for a class object:  its attributes, and recursively the attributes  
>     of its bases.  
>   for any other object: its attributes, its class's attributes, and  
>     recursively the attributes of its class's base classes.
> ```

i found maybe there are  problems  in the help file of dir builtin function.for example:

```
class  AddrBookEntry(object):
   'address book entry class'
   def __init__(self,nm,ph):
     self.name=nm
     self.phone=ph
   def updatePhone(self,newph):
     self.phone=newph
     print 'Updated phone # for :' ,self.name

dir(AddrBookEntry('tom','123'))
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'name', 'phone', 'updatePhone']
```

1.`dir()` can list the method of object ,not only attributes
the `updatePhone` is method ,not attribute.

2.how can i know which is the attribute,which is method in the output of dir()?

Comment: What is your expected output here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Methods *are* attributes in Python.
2. Check the various attributes on them. Methods have `im_*` attributes.

Comment: or 2. `[name for name in dir(whatever) if callable(getattr(whatever, name))]`

Comment: `callable()` is unreliable since functions are first-class objects in Python, but are not methods.

Comment: I suppose you're talking about objects that implement `__call__`. While that's not *so* rare an edge-case, I still think what I said was a reasonable approximation of what OP was looking for. Filtering by `'method' in repr()` or `inspect.ismethod` would be likewise unreliable.

Answer (score 2):

You kind of get a feel for telling the difference, but methods *are* attributes, so the only way to be really sure is to check.

Here's a function that will break it down for you:

```
def dirf(obj=None):
    """Get the output of dir() as a tuple of lists of callables and non-callables."""
    d = ([],[])
    for name in dir(obj):
        if callable(getattr(obj, name, locals().get(name))):
            d[0].append(name)
        else:
            d[1].append(name)
    return d
```

`inspect.getmembers` has a nice shortcut for getting callable members:

```
from inspect import getmembers
getmembers(obj, callable)
```

but beware of its own predicates! `inspect.ismethod` will only be `True` for methods *implemented in Python*. Many core objects' methods (`[].sort`, for example) do not meet that criteria.

Answer (score 1):

The help file is correct. In Python, methods are attached to classes (and instances of those classes) in exactly the same way as any other attribute. In order to distinguish a simple attribute from a callable one, you'll have to dereference it:

```
>>> type(AddrBookEntry('tom','123').phone)
<type 'str'>
>>> type(AddrBookEntry('tom','123').updatePhone)
<type 'instancemethod'>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to know the attributes of an object use the `__dict__` attribute.  E.g.:

```
>>> entry = AddrBookEntry('tom','123')
>>> entry.__dict__
{'name': 'tom', 'phone': '123'}
```

`dir()` is intended for debugging.  Using it in production code is probably a bad idea.  Exactly what it returns isn't very well defined.

Comment: -1 Dicts have keys and values. Attributes are something else, and all objects have attributes, whether or not they implement `__dict__`.

Comment: @kojori: Fundamentally objects implement __getattribute__ and __setattribute__ methods which are invoked when attributes are accessed.  The Python object model has no concept of attribute, those are implemented at a higher level.  If you create classes which inherit from `object` then instances of that class (and the class objects) will have attributes, and those attributes will be stored in a `__dict__`.

Comment: I see what you're saying, and why you're saying it, but OP asked specifically about `dir`, and your answer doesn't explain the difference between `dir(obj)` and `obj.__dict__`. That said, I would remove my downvote, but I need you to edit the answer before I can.