# Python code organization help: importing functions

Tags: python, module, package, code-organization

I have written some code, but it's all located in one file. It's sort of annoying to work with now because it's so long. So I'm thinking I should put all the function in a different file and just import them. I'm just not sure about the best way to go about doing this.

Current Code:

```
import glob, os
import csv as csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sys

def create_list(var):      
    stuff
def store_table(var):
    stuff
def geo_info(var):
    stuff 
def factor_loads(var):
    stuff  
def add_loads(var):
    stuff 
def calc_bypass_stress(var):
    a lot of stuff
def calcloads(var): 
    tons of stuff and calls other functions above    

for i in list:
   for k in another_list:
       calcloads(var)
```

I'm thinking that I could split it up so the functions that do lookups and create tables are in `tables.py`; anything that calculates stuff is in `calc_stuff.py` and I run everything from `thehead.py`:

**`tables.py`**

```
def create_list(var):      
    stuff
def store_table(var):
    stuff
def geo_info(var):
    stuff
def factor_loads(var):
    stuff
def add_loads(var):
    stuff
```

**`calc_stuff.py`**

```
def calc_bypass_stress(var):
    a lot of stuff
def calcloads(var): 
    tons of stuff and calls other functions above
```

**`thehead.py`**

```
import glob, os
import csv as csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sys
from tables import *
from calc_stuff import *

for i in list:
   for k in another_list:
       calcloads(var)
```

Some questions:

1) Will this work?

2) Almost all of my functions use something from Pandas, Numpy, etc. Do I need to import those packages inside each of the .py files? Or just at `thehead.py`?

3) From `thehead.py` I'm calling a function (`calcloads`) that is located in `calc_stuff.py` which uses functions located in `tables.py`. Should I have kept all functions in one file as opposed to splitting functions up into different files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. You need to import the packages in each of the .py files.
3. It's not a problem to split the functions up into different files. If your files are becoming very long, it would definitely be a good idea.

Comment: 1) When you say to import packages in each .py file, do I also import the files I created into each file?

2) Would I put `from calc_stuff import *` in the calc_stuff.py file, though?

3) Do I put `from calc_stuff import *` in tables.py?

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) No, a script shouldn't try to import itself. 3) Yes and no. You need an import statement there, but wildcard imports are strongly discouraged in Python, so I would suggest `import calc_stuff` instead.

Answer (score 2):

I think @tjohnson 's answer is excellent. I would just add something to question 3. It sounds like you have written a lot of functions, and you are trying to make your code / files more manageable by putting the functions which are not under "active development" into a sort of library. In that case, yes it is not a problem to store your functions in a set of separate files. But, going by the "flat is better than nested" principle, it may improve ease of lookup to put them all in one very long `.py` file, and then put a table of contents in the comments of that file, or print a table of contents on the fly after importing it.

One quick and dirty way to get the table of contents is as follows. Suppose your very long file is called `mymod1.py`. Then you can write:

*EDITED TO SIMPLIFY:* (using an idea from @kojiro [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14514168/4398863))

```
from mymod1 import * 
import mymod1 # to get it in the namespace
def my_toc(module):
    exclude = ['date','pprint'] # list of callables imported via `from foo import bar`
    for item in dir(module):
        if (item not in exclude and
            callable(getattr(module, item, locals().get(item)))):
            print(item)
my_toc(mymod1)
```

Output:

```
myfunc_1
myfunc_2
myfunc_3 # etc
```